# Rabbitmq: Node down

Tags: tcp, rabbitmq, ubuntu-16.04, firewall, rabbitmqctl

I am getting node down error on rabbitmq, this is happening sometimes.

Able to see the below error when I execute: `sudo rabbitmqctl status` or `sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues`

```
Error: unable to connect to node : nodedown
connected to epmd (port 4369) on host-name
epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
can't establish TCP connection, reason: timeout 
suggestion: blocked by firewall?
```

version: {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.9"}

os: Ubuntu 16.04

I have checked hostname which is ok with me, not changed since the installation

Also able to telnet localhost 25672

What could be the reason behind this error and possible solution?

And one more question, I am checking node status using below API

```
curl -s GET http://edx:edx@127.0.0.1:15672/api/healthchecks/node/
```

Is above API ok or not to check the health status of the node? Please suggest if there is anything else. I have set up one shell script which will call this API and if status is not ok then it will restart rabbitmq-server service. Script is executed from cron every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your rabbitmq node is... down. `rabbitmqctl` needs a running node to perform these commands.

If you're using systemd, you can check the service status:

```
service rabbitmq-server status
```

Or just try to restart the node:

```
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Telnet on port 25672 tells you the rabbitmqctl is running, but RabbitMQ itself does not run on that port (by default, it's listening on 5672).

Comment: rabbitmq-server is up and running, 
Yes, by restarting the app error is gone but its not solution for me as I don't know when this will happen on the server.

Comment: Anything in RabbitMQ logs? Or in syslog (RabbitMQ possibily killed by the system if resources go low)?